# JUnit test cases - Cannot see classes

Tags: java, junit, package

I am struggling with rearranging the heiracrchy in my project. I have organised all classes in to packages (but incorrectly) and now I think I need to nest my packages opposed to having them at separate levels?

Now, when I try and write test classes for the classes in my project I can not see the relevant methods without using reflection for everything.

The heirarchy I have at the moment is
[image]

What do i need to change to be able to test without using reflection for everything and to be able to correctly nest my packages?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by 'see the relevant methods' and 'using reflection'? Maybe you mean that the visibility of your methods are the default package level? You can fix this by making them public: `public void testMyStuff()`

Comment: When i create objects of the classes in my test class they never seem to have any methods available?

Comment: Can you show us a minimal example of a class and its test so we can see what you are actually doing?

Answer (score 4):

Arrange your test files to have the same package structure as your src files. That way any method in co.uk.mine.SomeClass could have a corresponding co.uk.mine.SomeClassTest which is able to access any non-private methods. Private methods can be accessed by reflection. Your ide should allow you to set up 2 filder structures to keep test code separate:

```
../src/co/uk/mine/SomeClass.java
../test/co/uk/mine/SomeClassTest.java
```

Comment: Yes. This is the conventional way to organise unit test classes - the test class is in the same package as the class under test, so it can see its package-access methods, but in a different source folder, so test and main code are separated. There are people who will tell you to do it another way, but it's safe to ignore them.

Comment: It's worth adding that the standard in the Java world is 'Maven layout', where inside the project's root, you have a directory `src`, inside which you have a `main` and a `test`, inside each of which is a directory `java` that is actually the source root. There's no particular reason to adhere to this standard, but you might come across it in the wild.

Comment: Agree to the maven layout (its my preference), but plenty of people us ant or other conventions that may be different. I guess the point is to use 2 directory structures on the class path that allow for mirrored packages but separate folders. Again, I prefer Maven and would encourage a look if you've never used it.

Answer (score 2):

The default accessibility of methods is 'package visibility'. See this article from IBM on this:

> http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/ws-tip-mem-visibility.html

To make your methods visible to classes outside the package, make them public:

```
public void myMethod() {...}
```

Comment: I realise this, it is just that even changing them to public does not change anything, i get no default proposals for the code completion.

Comment: Does the compiler allow you to access them (without code completion)? Maybe you should clean the entire project (menu project->clean...)

Comment: Oh, and any inner classes you are using must be made public as well! And if all these things are not working I think you should write more in the question on the exact situation (specific classes using/used, package locations, etc.), maybe it helps to find the answer.